# addition inside Razor syntax not working in for loop

Tags: c#, razor

The following code works fine..

```
@for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    <p>Line #: @i</p>
}
```

This will give result:

```
Line #:0
Line #:1
Line #:2
//and so on..
```

What do I do to get values from Line#:1 rather than Line#:0.

So result would be..

```
Line #:1
Line #:2
Line #:3
and so on..
```

I tried .. `@i++` as well as `@i+1`, does not work...

Comment: can you please elaborate the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bracket it:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    <p>Line #: @(i + 1)</p>
}
```

Otherwise only the `i` is treated as part of the razor statement and the +1 is treated as a literal meaning instead of getting

```
<p>Line #: 1</p>
```

You'd end up with

```
<p>Line #: 0+1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access a piece of info within data?

```
@for(var i = 0; i < (data.length-1); i++)
{
    <p>Line #: @data[i+1]</p>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start i from 1

```
@for(var i = 1; i < (data.length+1); i++)
{
    <p>Line #: @i</p>
}
```

Comment: if you start from 1 like you did, you don't get all elements. you get only `data.length - 1`